# vscode no class files in target path but have package path, why?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation

When I run "mvn clean package" command in terminal, I got classes files. Bug when I click "run", I met "can not find or load main class" error. And I find the class files was gone. Why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the real error in my workspaceStorage log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2022-06-17 13:35:28.583
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.Trees.instance(Trees.java:82)
   at com.mageddo.aptools.textblock.TextBlockProcessor.<init>(TextBlockProcessor.java:38)
   at com.mageddo.lombokext.LombokExtAnnotationProcessor.init(LombokExtAnnotationProcessor.java:35)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.apt.pluggable.core.dispatch.IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.discoverNextProcessor(IdeAnnotationProcessorManager.java:97)
```

It was because lombok-ext-2.3.4.jar which added in my pom.xml, and this occurs errors when compiling. I removed it and everything works well.